# ruby capistrano cashed -- runs old code after deployment

Tags: ruby, apache, caching, deployment, capistrano

All of a sudden after cap production deploy runs and copies the code (as it had done in the past). All the haml changes work fine but models changes not. I can even remove model and run cap production deploy and it will deploy but will run some old model code because there is not model in the current directory that points to latest release. just started to happen. Worked fine for month. Is there a way to find out what code is executed and from where? I restarted apache server and linux server, checked http.conf to see if anything changed. Everything looks find. Ideas? Advices?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Considering you've posted zero code, zero in the way of concrete errors, and have only vaguely described the problem, this will require a psychic and/or a wizard to solve. Can you please improve the question by adding specifics?

Comment: There are no errors. Just new code is not picked up even if I can see it the current directory that httpd.conf is pointing too. It started to happen all of a sudden. Is there a pre-compiled ruby code somewhere in cache? I can move empty code to current, restart the service and application will still be running? in my shared directory I have bin, public and bundle dirs. Can I delete them? Can they cause a problem? bin has files that has latest timestamps -- thanks!!!

Comment: Unless you're using Rubinius, there's really no such thing as "pre-compiled Ruby code". I'm at a loss to even understand what your problem is.

Comment: ok. that's what i think. i came from .net world and classes are compiled. Anyway, how would it be possible then that code moved using cap production deployed without some rb model files and when server is restarting application runs. httpd.confd points to that directory. here is a snapshot from httpd.conf

Comment: ok. that's what i think too. i came from .net world and classes are compiled. Anyway, how would it be possible then that code moved using cap production deployed without some rb model files and when server is restarting application runs. httpd.confd points to that directory.

Comment: Capistrano is supposed to create a copy of your application and promote it live if and only if it checks out. It should never do a partial deploy.